# Pass float parameters from html to javascript

Tags: javascript, var

I've got a little issue here.

What I'm trying to do is pass some parameters from html to javascript. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="percentage">52.338</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var pctg = document.getElementById("percentage");
alert(pctg);
```

But it doesn't work well. Could u tell me how to fix it? I've tried 'parseFloat' and some related things, but cannot work it out yet... Thx in advance.

Comment: `parseFloat('52.338') === 52.338 && Number('52.338') === 52.338`. You're just forgetting to do your favourite way to get the contents; `.textContent`, `.innerText` or `.innerHTML`. Also remember that an _id_ should be unique; if you want to do this multiple times put a number on the end or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is the text content of the element instead of the element itself. Some browsers (older IEs of course) use `innerText` instead of [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent) so it's a good idea to use both properties:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("percentage");
var text = elem.textContent || elem.innerText;
```

If you actually want a number instead of just a string use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on the string.

---

Depending on what you are doing it might be more advisable to store the value in a `data-` attribute though. Then you can simply use `.getAttribute('data-whatever')` to access it instead of having to deal with getting the text content of the element. In case you use jQuery it'd become even nicer as you could then use `.data('whatever')` which would already return a number. Modern browsers also support direct access to data attributes via the `dataset` property; but you probably don't want to use this as it would break with older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

`pctg` will contain an element, not the text of the element. Try `alert(pctg.innerHTML)`.

You can use `parseFloat(pctg.innerHTML)` if you need the floating point.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the innerText of the element and then parse the value like so:

```
var pctg = document.getElementById("percentage").innerText;
var floatNumber = parseFloat(pctg);
```